# Ruby radio_button_tag not obeying `checked: true`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

For some reason, this `radio_button_tag` within a `form_tag` block will not obey the checked argument. I've tried `true`, `:checked => checked`, `checked: true` and all different combinations.

Here is my code with the 3rd argument as `true`

```
<%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :followers_count, true, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
<%= label :metric_type, 'Followers', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>
```

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) reads

```
radio_button_tag 'color', "green", true, class: "color_input"
# => <input checked="checked" class="color_input" id="color_green" name="color" type="radio" value="green" />
```

However, in the DOM it renders as:

```
<input type="radio" name="metric_type" id="metric_type_followers_count" value="followers_count">
```

**== UPDATE =====================**

`ruby -v ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]`

`rails -v Rails 5.0.1`

Note - I have not set any styles on these classes yet.

```
    <div>
    <%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'analytics', action: 'mega_chart'), method: :get, remote: true do %>

    <p class='chart-legend-header'>Social</p>
    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :followers_count, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :metric_type, 'Followers', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :views_count, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :metric_type, 'Views', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :comments_count, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :metric_type, 'Comments', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :shares_count, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :metric_type, 'Shares', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :dislikes_count, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :metric_type, 'Dislikes', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :media_count, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :metric_type, 'Posts', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-metrics-social' %>

    <p class='chart-legend-header'>Options</p>
    <%= radio_button_tag :date_range, 30.days.ago, true, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :date_range, '30 Days', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-options-date' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :date_range, 90.days.ago, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :date_range, '90 Days', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-options-date' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :benchmark_type, 'daily_gain', true, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :benchmark_type, 'Daily Gain', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-options-benchmark' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :benchmark_type, 'total', :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
    <%= label :benchmark_type, 'Total', :class => 'chart-radio-label chart-radio-options-benchmark' %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Refresh Chart', :id => 'chart-submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like in the view
[image: form in view]

Comment: `ruby -v ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]`
`rails -v Rails 5.0.1`

Comment: @uDaY hmm that's weird. on inspect it shows `<input type="radio" name="metric_type" id="metric_type_followers_count" value="followers_count" class="chart-radio-icon" checked="checked">` but the button itself is not checked

Comment: @uDaY yes, i saved the code, refreshed the page a few times, restarted the rails server, tried incognito mode, and even tried a different browser. please note that this is ruby.

Comment: I know its ruby and all I dont know is if you have some magic with your css classes or something..

Comment: @uDaY You've deleted your answer here so I can't reply to your comment directly, but keep [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) in mind, please.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax Could you [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]? Make the absolute smallest (readable) Ruby/ERB file you can that has this problem. It could be an issue with a model or something, which wouldn't be visible here.

Comment: @uDaY I did. Hence the second half of my comment, which was suggesting that what you saw was a default value. The method's declaration isn't how you call the method. The copious examples directly above it in the documentation comment are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon inspecting the HTML further, I discovered that all of the radio buttons were rendering as `checked="checked"` so I marked each of the 3rd arguments as `false` except for the one I wanted as true!

```
<%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :followers_count, true, :class => 'chart-radio-icon' %>
<%= label_tag(:metric_type_followers_count, 'Followers', :class => 'chart-label chart-label-social') %>
```